# If something can be achieved using CSS or JavaScript, which will render faster?

Tags: css, javascript, page-speed

I have two working solutions for hover navigation that I've built. One solution uses JS, one use CSS. My question is, assuming a browser is JS-enabled, which solution will work faster?

I'll most likely opt for CSS anyway to avoid given non-JS browsers trouble, but I was curious. I'm not sure of a way to programatically test my solutions with the necessary resolution, but I presume this has been documented somewhere.

Comment: Why does it matter? It would be a matter of microseconds at most, in any normal setup. If there is a reason to suspect that the speed difference could be noticeable to the human eye, the odds are that your navigation system or its implementation is far too complex.

Comment: It certainly does matter. Even with a quick jQuery and or CSS menu if it's fast enough that you can't tell the difference but the code varies by a few kb it adds up and when you're paying for server resources that's what matters. 1 million hits a month x a few kb adds up. Why do you think some stack exchange sites don't use meta descriptions to save on bandwidth. So yes it matters and you should always be trying to optimize your code.

Comment: @Anagio, the question was about rendering faster, not amount of code.

Comment: Flagging to close. This is pretty much entirely theoretical, and impossible to address in this blanket manner, anyway. You can only evaluate specific cases.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - While rendering times may be nearly the same, the amount of code DOES matter greatly because not only does it save bandwidth, it saves time to transmit to the end user. That's why we like to `gzip` our content before serving it. It saves time and bandwidth both. (Thus loading in the browser faster).

Comment: @Dan you can test each type of navigation on your own domain using Google Insights, and Pingdom. Put the CSS styles for your menu in a separate style sheet just for testing. Then test each CSS and jQuery method. See how long it takes to download a jQuery+CSS file then just a CSS file. You'll also be able to see the file size. Minifying and gzipping also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a similar question on stack overflow they said...

> CSS ist for Style. JavaScript should be only for the application
>   logic... Generally you want to separate the application logic from the
>   design & animation. Beside that it performs much better especially on
>   mobile devices

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716885/responsive-design-method-for-collapsing-a-div

So if you can use pure CSS go with that

Comment: Thanks. I think the quote you give is a lot more relevant to my question than the question/answer in the link, but helpful nonetheless.

Comment: How does this address the question about rendering speed?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela because it has to do with the amount of code as well as one performing better.

Answer (score 2):

Definitively use CSS pseudo-class :hover. It will be faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into similar issues, hence my clicking on the link. I learned a lot from this article on writing efficient CSS from Mozilla: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS